# HTML Input Checkbox return 'On' instead of 'True' when submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a MVC3 app using Project Awesome (http://awesome.codeplex.com/), but I am getting a weird behaviour on checkboxes. I have the following simple Html within a Modal popup `<input type="checkbox" class="check-box" name="IsDeleted">`

When I submit the form containing this element, its post value is 'on' instead of the expected 'true' (when element is checked).

Does anybody know why this is? I am assuming there may be some javascript somewhere messing with the form data, but wanted to check whether there isn't some HTML I am missing.

Thanks

Comment: I had this when I was using e.target.value, when it should be e.target.checked hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Set the checkboxes `value` attribute to `true` and you will get `true` in your post value.

Comment: This is true if and only if the user checks the box.  If not checked nothing gets posted.  Also, MVC's binding mechanism will set the value to null if nothing gets posted for that checkbox.

Comment: ie:  <label><input type="checkbox" id="SomeID" name="SomeName" onclick="CBSelectedValueToTrue(this);" >Weight</label>......function CBSelectedValueToTrue(cb)
    {
        if (cb.checked)
        {
            cb.value = "true";
        }
    }

Comment: Doing this will return true, but never a `false` value?

Answer (score 11):

It's browser specific, I suppose, what to send when value is undefined. You need to defined `value` attribute on your radios/checkboxes to be sure what will be passed back to you. I would suggest `value="1"`

Answer (score 9):

set `data-val="true" and value="true"` by deafult... 
if checkbox is checked then returns true

Answer (score 2):

**Check Checkbox is checked or not if checked set Hidden field true else set hidden field false.**

```
$('#hiddenFieldId').val($('#CheckBoxId').attr('checked')=='checked')
```

Answer (score 1):

Surely you should just check if it is set - the value that it sends across is irrelevant, if it's not checked, then nothing at all gets sent when you POST.

Comment: Is that specified in W3C? I thought this was browser-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked!
I ended up on a hacky way after seeing the serialised form object just before posting to controller/action. Its not safe in case if anyone would have any textboxes inside that may contain ampersands. In my case, i had an array of checkboxes, so I did this hack after I am very sure, i won't have problems.

```
var formData = $("#form").serialize();
formData = formData.replaceAll('=on&','=true&');
if (formData.endsWith('=on'))
{
 formData = formData.substring(0, formData.length - 3) + "=true";
}
```

Hope it helps to those 'someone' with my scenario. Happy hacking.

Answer (score 0):

if you do this :

```
const checkbox = document.getElementById("myCheckbox");
console.log(checkbox.value);
```

you will get the output `on` instead of `true or false`

then change to :

```
const checkbox = document.getElementById("myCheckbox");
console.log(checkbox.checked);
```

it will print a boolean value.

Answer (score -2):

Use jQuery for cross-browser decision. And it will return *true* or *false* anyway.

```
$('#check-box-id').attr('checked' ) == true
```

if your checkbox has an id *check-box-id*. For your current version use *the next* (select by class name):

```
$('.check-box').attr('checked' ) == true
```

Answer (score -2):

Use jQuery

```
var out=$('.check-box').is('checked')
```

If checkbox is checked out=true
else out=false

Answer (score -2):

In HTML, add a input type="hidden" above checkbox:

```
<input name="active" id="activeVal" type="hidden">
<input id="active" type="checkbox">
```

Then, add a script as below:

```
$('#activeVal').val($('#active').is(':checked'));
$('#active').change(function() {
     $('#activeVal').val($('#active').is(':checked'));
});
```

When you do eg. `$('#your-form').serialize()` in jQuery, you will get value of checkbox when checked `active: true` or uncheck `active: false`