# Checkbox boolean doesn't seem to submit to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, boolean

I have a register form with a checkbox that indicates whether a user should have admin_rights, the problem however is that this doesn't get trough to the database.
If I check the header it does however get trough with `&admin_rights=on`, I declared this value in multiple ways such as `$rights = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['admin_rights']);` or `$param_admin = trim($_POST["admin_rights"]);` but none of those seem to work.

The code that enters it into the database is

```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, admin_rights) VALUES (?, ?, '$param_admin')";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_password);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Redirect to login page
                header("location: login.php");
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
```

```
 <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="checkbox" name="admin_rights" class="form-control checkbox" id="admin_rights"> 
                 <label>Admin rights?</label>


            </div>
```

The other data, such as the password and the username do get trough so I'm pretty sure the problem is in the boolean checkbox.

I'm not sure exactly how to fix this so that the admin_rights does save as a boolean when checked.

Comment: Checkbox checked will return you "on", so you can check it in your php code like : 'checkbox == "on" ? true : false' or you can set the value directly into your html, check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441654/html-input-checkbox-return-on-instead-of-true-when-submitting-form

Comment: _“but none of those seem to work”_ - and that means what, _exactly_? Do you get to see your own custom “Something went wrong” error message? In that case, please _go read up on_ how to properly debug MySQLi queries executed via PHP.

Comment: (And why that ugly mix between prepared statement with placeholders, and a value inserted _directly_ into the query?)

Comment: @leobrl that seemed to work, thanks!

Comment: You are misusing prepared statements. Stop using `mysqli_real_escape_string` and bind all params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set value="1" 

so if user check this box then value=1 saves into database and in database set default value to 0 in admin_rights field.
with 1 value field you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Could you add more details and perhaps format your answer?

Comment: <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="admin_rights" class="form-control checkbox" id="admin_rights">                                                                                                   Now this checkbox have default value 1 if user check this box then in database 1 value saved in db field else 0 save in database fields you have to set default value 0 in database field..